# PyGtk draw mark over scrollbar

Tags: gtk, scrollbar, pygtk

Is there any way to draw some marks "over" a scrollbar in PyGtk as done, for example, in Chrome with the search results?

I found some help in [this](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq06.004.htp) FAQ but I still need to place a drawing area over the scrollbar which is, in fact, part of a scrolledwindow...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put a drawing area on the scrollbar - just do your drawing in the `do_expose_event` handler.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @ptomato. I have been looking for examples on how to do the drawing but I couldn't find any. Could you, please, point me to some sample code? Thanks :)

Comment: You can try [this](http://www.pygtk.org/articles/cairo-pygtk-widgets/cairo-pygtk-widgets.htm) tutorial on how to draw on a widget using Cairo. Just keep in mind, instead of drawing on a `DrawingArea`, you are drawing directly onto the `ScrolledWindow`.

Comment: Thanks again @ptomato, with the example you gave me now I can draw over any widget; now it's just a matter to do it over the crollbar.